# Div height does not stretch

Tags: html, css

This is blowing my mind. I have a wrapper div and 2 divs inside it, one of the divs its height is 100% but does not stretch to fit the wrapper.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmL6e18/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="inner_left">
Just<br />Some<br />Words
</div>

<div class="inner_right">
Anything
</div>

</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width:auto !important;
    height:auto !important;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.inner_left {
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    width:270px;
    height:auto !important;
    border:1px solid #666;
    float:left;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.inner_right {
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #666;
    float:right;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I need the div (`inner_right`) to auto fit the height of the wrapper. So whenever the wrapper's height shrinks or stretches, this div stretches to the maximum height of the wrapper.

Anyone knows why my code isn't working? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Using this method, you'll need to specify a height for `div.wrapper` in order to reference it with a child's percentage height.

Comment: `height: 100%` doesn't work that way with dynamic content. Flexbox (if you don't need to support older browsers) is probably the best way to accomplish this. You could also use `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; /* whatever you want */
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner_left {
  width: 270px;
}
.inner_right {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner_left">Just
    <br />Some
    <br />Words</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Anything</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@showdev is right, the parent element needs to have its height explicitly set in order for the height of the child element to work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set 100% height to whole document:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and for wrapper class:

```
.wrapper {
  width:auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  float:left;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmL6e18/1/)